# Using QSerialPort to write something with quote marks to a serial device

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qbytearray

I'm trying to write a Lua command to a serial device. The Lua command has quote marks in it, which my code is not getting along with. The command is part of the startup sequence that I would like to implement. I need to get "wd = require "word" \r\n" to send to the device so I tried this:

`QByteArray const CMD_ALPHA = "wd = require \"word\" \r\n";`

but it retained the slashes. If I do not have the slashes then the code doesn't compile.
CMD_ALPHA is passed to a queuing function then written to the device using the write function in QSerialPort. Is there a way I can send the command, complete with the speech marks?

Comment: How did you determine that it "retained the slashes"?

Comment: @Botje By having the device echo what I'm sending. It echoes exactly what is above, with the slashes.

Comment: and _how_ are you sending it to the device? If you call `toString` it *will* reinsert backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

**The main thing you need to know: the `CMD_ALPHA` array you wrote does not contain any values ​​at all that correspond to the `\` character.**

The byte array described below contains only one value.
This single value corresponds to the `"`  symbol.
Its size is equal to one:

```
QByteArray baWithQuoteSymbolOnly = "\"";
```

The reason you see the `\` characters is that your output tool (debugger output, terminal, etc) decide to show all the symbols in the array + represent several symbols in a "non-printable" way.
For example, printable way to output of `\n` symbol is a line break, not \n.

Run the code below for better understanding.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    /*
    The byte array below contains only 1 symbol "
    It does not contain \ symbols at all.
    Its size is equal to one.
    */
    QByteArray baWithQuoteSymbolOnly = "\"";
    qDebug() << baWithQuoteSymbolOnly.size();

    /* 
    But it can be printed with quotation characters 
    and with escaping of non-printable characters
    */
    qDebug() << baWithQuoteSymbolOnly;

    /*
    You can print it WITHOUT quotation characters 
    and WITHOUT escaping of non-printable characters
    */
    qDebug().noquote() << baWithQuoteSymbolOnly;

    QByteArray const CMD_ALPHA  = "wd = require \"word\" \r\n";
    qDebug() << CMD_ALPHA;
    qDebug().noquote() << CMD_ALPHA;

    // output every element that CMD_ALPHA array actually contains
    for (int i=0; i<CMD_ALPHA.size(); i++)
    {        
        char asciiSymbol = CMD_ALPHA.at(i);
        int value = CMD_ALPHA.at(i);

        qDebug().noquote() << "ascii symbol =" << asciiSymbol << "value in hex =" << QString::number(value, 16);
    }

    // Now see what ASCII code does backslash symbol really have
    char realBackslash = '\\';

    qDebug().noquote() << "backslash symbol =" << realBackslash 
        << "value in hex =" << QString::number(realBackslash, 16);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Additional note. QByteArray is actually wrapper class to store an array of 8-bit values. It is not even an array of symbols and not a string until you decide to show it. A string is just a form of representation of an array of digital values. Output with adding of non-printable characters is a kind of representation of strings.